# Does OBD II explicitly or implicitly include forward/reverse information?

Tags: obd-ii

From my understanding, OBD II does not directly tell if a car is in forward or reverse gear. I wonder what the best way to derive such information from OBD data if there is any.

Following the discussion in [this post](http://www.dfrobot.com/forum/index.php?topic=875.0), specifically I would like to know if [PID62](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs) says forward when it is positive and reverse when it is negative. If not, is there any other other PID can reveal forward/reverse information with a foolproof mapping logic. If any, please specify the PID and the mapping logic.

Comment: Sounds like from the thread you posted, what you are looking for is not open in the public realm in OBD-II info.

Answer (score 3):

As I know you could reach the negative value at PID62 even if you break with the gear box. It's not the best way to find out such a stuff. The reverse gear sensor is straight forward, and just open and close the circuit. Only the cars with this "efficient gear shift assistance stuff", that show you when to shift support this gear information ( Polo 6R and so one). But it's very special parameter and there is no official PID for it.